# Understanding an argument about $\lim \sup x(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, limsup-and-liminf

I am reading a paper and I am stuck understanding some argument. I have the following system of equations (different that the paper one). all parameters are assumed to be positive.

$$x' = x(1-x) - \frac{cxy}{A+x},$$
$$y' = By(1-\frac{\delta y}{ax+b}).$$

I want to prove that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sup x(t) \leq 1$. I have that
$$x' \leq x(1-x), $$
but i don't know how using this fact, we obtain $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sup x(t) \leq 1$. Moreover, they show that there exists $T>0$ such that $x(t) < M,$ for $t > T,$ where $M>1$. Now the equation that the paper has is the following:
$$y' = \delta y(\beta -\frac{y}{x}),$$
Again they claim that for $t>T$, we have:
$$y' \leq \delta y(\beta -\frac{y}{M}),$$
so that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sup y(t) \leq M\beta.$ It is valid to say in my case that for $t>T,$ we have:
$$y' \leq By(1-\frac{\delta y}{aM+b}),$$
and conclude that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sup y(t) \leq \frac{aM+b}{\delta}$. I am not understanding at all how they obtain the $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sup y(t)$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sup x(t).$

Comment: I don’t know if you assume $y$ is also positive.  But if you assume $x’(t) \leq x(t)(1-x(t))$ then:
If $x(t)>1$ then it cannot increase. If $\epsilon>0$ and $x(t)>1+\epsilon$ then $x’(t) \leq -\epsilon$ and eventually $x(\tau) \leq 1+\epsilon$ for some time $\tau > t$ (and hence all time thereafter).

Comment: Something happened between equations $y' = \delta y (\beta - y/x)$ and $y' \leq y(\beta - y/M)$.  A factor $\delta$ mysteriously disappeared. Else, it would make sense that if $x\leq M$ then $-y^2/x \leq -y^2/M$.

Comment: yes $y$ is also positive, both $x$ and $y$ are positive. I fix the missing parameter

Comment: So, then my comment answered your question, yes?

Comment: yes, I will work towards the problem and update as soon as possible, thanks.